sveltekit saving offline/online status for the entire app
What is the best approach to save and use online/offline status all over a client side only app created with sveltekit?
Session/Cookies?
The app deployed as static using addapter_static, as PWA with offline support
In order to avoid writing the following code on every page.
// addEventListener version
window.addEventListener("offline", (event) => {
  console.log("The network connection has been lost.");
});

// onoffline version
window.onoffline = (event) => {
  console.log("The network connection has been lost.");
};

According to the changes status I want to change the top menu background color, show background image on every page and in some cases disable buttons

From Svelte 5.11 on, you can import this as a reactive value directly from a Svelte module:
import { online } from 'svelte/reactivity/window';

online.current // continuously updates

Pre v5, you could wrap the event handling in a store in its own module. E.g.
<script>
    import { online } from './online.js';
</script>

<p>You are {$online ? 'online' : 'offline'}</p>

// online.js
import { readable } from 'svelte/store';

export const online = readable(navigator.onLine, (set, update) => {
    const ctrl = new AbortController();
    for (const event of ['online', 'offline'])
        window.addEventListener(
            event,
            () => set(navigator.onLine),
            { signal: ctrl.signal },
        );

    return () => ctrl.abort();
});

Playground

Prior to v5, in which file do I need to update the store?

@ZAky: It can be any file, I added an example.
